# how to process response data of backend service in APIM using azure function

Tags: azure-functions, apim

I have apim endpoint which sends get-request to the backend service, in which the backend service sends back a large json content which should be restructured to some format/datastructure.I have created an azure function that can reformat the response json content but i can't figure out how to bind the zure function to the backend service response json data in the apim. any help would be much apprecaited.

I couldnt get any direction on how to start. i am expecting the solution to be on how to add the data processing azure function to the apim, i.e

1 - apim sends get request to the backend service.
2 - backend service sends back json response, but here the new added azure function shoud process the json response & returns the result to the apim request handling task

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`send-request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/send-request-policy) policy in the outbound section of your policy document for your API.

That being said, instead of using a function to do this transformation, you could also use the [`set-body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-body-policy) policy as well. You could explore the [liquid template approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-body-policy#using-liquid-templates-with-set-body) which could be simpler to implement as well.